# MongoDB document and collection are null

Tags: java, mongodb

I've been trying to use MongoDB to manage my data, however currently my implementation results in this error:

```
 Cannot invoke "com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.deleteOne(org.bson.conversions.Bson)" because "collection" is null
```

or

```
Cannot invoke "org.bson.Document.toJson()" because "doc" is null
```

This is my code for declaring the collection and database:

```
 MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://username:password@database.on8dy.mongodb.net/project?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("database");
            MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("collection");
```

The first error occurs here:

```
collection.deleteOne(Filters.eq("username", username));
```

The second error occurs when I try this:

```
return doc.toJson();
```

Both of these are in separate methods, but I don't think that is what is causing the error.

P.S. don't worry about the naming, I just replaced what I have with the generic wording for my username, password, database and collection.

Comment: You need to include the code where the problem occurs. A complete example which reproduces your problem would be best.

Comment: sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: according to your URI, your db is called "project". do you use that name in "mongoClient.getDatabase"? (I'm asking because you mentioned that you replaced the actual names with generic wording)

Comment: no, i don't. That's also just replaced. Sorry about that.

Comment: anyway try to put db name coming after slash in URI, into "mongoClient.getDatabase"